FLUTTER ERROR bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon(null);
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
/Users/iptechpc/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_local_notifications-9.9.1/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:820: error: reference to bigLargeIcon is ambiguous
bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon(null);
^
both method bigLargeIcon(Bitmap) in BigPictureStyle and method bigLargeIcon(Icon) in BigPictureStyle match
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I TRY ALOT DO

Try:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
